# I'm having nan in Cross entropy which is not reasonable

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, theano, cross-entropy

I'm tracing back the problem in my network to detect the reason of having nan from the cross entropy.

I took the values from the network where exactly I start to have Nan and test them alone on another function.

Here I'm testing the 50 values together to find which one gave the NaN.

```
import  theano.tensor as T
import theano
s = T.fvector('s')
y = T.ivector('y')
d= -(y * T.log(s) + (1-y) * T.log(1-s)) #T.mean

x =[1.04693806  ,0.00685256, 1.20987034  ,0.0488876 ]

x_y = np.array((1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0), dtype=np.int32)
x = numpy.array(x, dtype=np.float32)

f = theano.function(inputs=[s, y], outputs=d)
print f(x, x_y)
```

and I have this result.

```
[ nan  0.00687615 nan  0.05012303]
```

So in order to see why the nan exist here I test the function on hand and on wolfarma and on theano itself. I took the one before the last and test it alone by:

```
t = T.scalar('t')
d= -(1 * T.log(t) + (0) * T.log(1-t))
f = theano.function(inputs=[t], outputs=d)
print f(1.20987034)
```

and the result is Not Nan.

```
-0.190513193607
```

So this number in the first function give NaN while it shouldn't ?

Comment: Why should it **not** be `NaN`?  The second term in your cross entropy equation would provide a negative argument to the `log` function which is why a `NaN` is occurring (i.e. negative `log` does not exist for real numbers).  The cross entropy equation is designed to only take values between 0 and 1.  You are specifically forcing values greater than 1 for those two elements in the array which is why `NaN` is occurring.

Comment: That's why there is (1-1) which multiply it by zero. in the second test for the same number I don't have Nan. The network is still learning and I might encounter higher value.

Comment: 0 multiplied by `NaN` is still `NaN`.  Try it for yourself. `import numpy as np; B = 0 * np.log(-2); print(B)`.  As for the reason why you are not getting `NaN` in that case, I'm unsure as to why that's happening but it does make sense that you are getting `NaN` for values greater than 1.

Comment: I did try the number alone. and I updated my question. I didn't get Nan.

Comment: That is definitely a bug. `log` with a negative input should not give a real valued number.  In the meantime, do you **have** to use cross entropy? What about a softmax loss?

Comment: I'm trying now to implement this network in this way. instead of having two outputs and applying softmax and log-likelihood, I'm taking only one output and apply cross-entropy. the problem caused because of Relu where this function doesn't range the output between 0 and 1 and cause higher value.

Comment: Using cross-entropy with ReLU is **not a good idea**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166595/how-to-apply-cross-entropy-on-rectified-linear-units.  Please rethink your network structure.

Comment: I agree with you. maybe I should use distance function instead of log function.

Comment: the implemented function is not a cross-entropy fct. In cross-entropy you use `log(q(x))` where `q(x)` is a probability distibution  i.e. it has values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @valentin yes it is a cross-entropy function. the problem with the input is not in the range between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, please do not use the cross entropy function. Use another loss function with a dynamic range that is within the previous layer before your loss.